# Why does "-less" sort after "hello" instead of before it?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I'm seeing some very strange sorting behaviour using CaseInsensitiveComparer.DefaultInvariant. Words that start with a leading hyphen "-" end up sorted as if the hyphen wasn't there rather than being sorted in front of actual letters which is what happens with other punctuation.

So given { "hello", ".net", "-less"} I end up with {".net", "hello", "-less" } instead of the expected {"-less", ".net", "hello"}.

Or, phrased as a test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var rg = new String[] { 
        "x", "z", "y", "-less", ".net", "- more", "a", "b"
    };

    Array.Sort(rg, CaseInsensitiveComparer.DefaultInvariant);

    Assert.AreEqual(
        "- more,-less,.net,a,b,x,y,z", 
        String.Join(",", rg)
    );
}
```

... which fails like this:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<- more,-less,.net,a,b,x,y,z>. 
Actual:  <- more,.net,a,b,-less,x,y,z>.
```

Any ideas what's going on?

#### Edit:

Looks like, by default .NET does fancy things when sorting strings which causes leading hyphens to be sorted into strange places so that co-op and coop sort together. Thus, if you want your leading hyphen words to end up and the begining with the other punctutation you have to tell it not not to:

```
Array.Sort(rg, (a, b) => String.CompareOrdinal(a, b));
```

Comment: It might be considered to be similar to a negative sign when appended with no whitespace

Comment: If only every question could be expressed as a unit test.

Comment: I don't know about point '.', but it looks like StringComparer.InvariantCulture just eats all the dashes '-' before making a comparison.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Comparison procedures use the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture  to determine the sort order and casing rules. String comparisons might have different results depending on the culture. For more information on culture-specific comparisons, see the System.Globalization namespace and Encoding and Localization.
>   [From here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.caseinsensitivecomparer.defaultinvariant.aspx)

The interesting part:

> A word sort performs a culture-sensitive comparison of strings in which certain nonalphanumeric Unicode characters might have special weights assigned to them. For example, the hyphen (-) might have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op" appear next to each other in a sorted list. 
>   [From here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Then OP can solve confusion as follows? "A string sort also performs a culture-sensitive comparison. It is similar to a word sort, except that there are no special cases, and all nonalphanumeric symbols come before all alphanumeric Unicode characters. Two strings can be compared using string sort rules by calling the CompareInfo.Compare method overloads that have an options parameter that is supplied a value of CompareOptions.StringSort. Note that this is the only method that the .NET Framework provides to compare two strings using string sort rules."

Comment: +1, good answer.  Explode your brain by contemplating the many different kinds of dashes, the one on your keyboard is always the wrong one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Answer (score 3):

To sort the strings in the way you need, you have to create a comparer class that compares strings using the [Compareinfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareinfo.aspxspecify). This class allow you to specify various methods of comparison, the one that best matches yor needs is OrdinalIgnoreCase.

From MSDN:

> Ignored Search Values
>
> Comparison operations, such as those
>   performed by the IndexOf or
>   LastIndexOf methods, can yield
>   unexpected results if the value to
>   search for is ignored. The search
>   value is ignored if it is an empty
>   string (""), a character or string
>   consisting of characters having code
>   points that are not considered in the
>   operation because of comparison
>   options, or a value with code points
>   that have no linguistic significance.
>   If the search value for the IndexOf
>   method is an empty string, for
>   example, the return value is zero.
>
> Note
>   When possible, the application
>   should use string comparison methods
>   that accept a CompareOptions value to
>   specify the kind of comparison
>   expected. As a general rule,
>   user-facing comparisons are best
>   served by the use of linguistic
>   options (using the current culture),
>   while security comparisons should
>   specify Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase.specify Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase.

I have modified your test case, and this one execute correctly:

```
public class MyComparer:Comparer<string>
{
    private readonly CompareInfo compareInfo;

    public MyComparer()
    {
        compareInfo = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name);
    }

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return compareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var rg = new String[] { 
    "x", "z", "y", "-less", ".net", "- more", "a", "b"
};

        Array.Sort(rg, new MyComparer());

        Assert.AreEqual(
            "- more,-less,.net,a,b,x,y,z",
            String.Join(",", rg)
        );


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that a dash immedately before a letter is being ignored, for purposes of sorting.  When you sort a list of words, you'd like "inter-nation" and "international" to be next to each other, wouldn't you?  A dash by itself, on the other hand, is considered significant.

Comment: Not really - I'd like (and expect) sorting of embedded non-alpha chars according to their position in the ASCII charset.  Are you saying that "inter-national" and "international" are the same according to this Comparer?

Answer (score 0):

Sort order is dependent on the culture, so you can't assume characters will sort in ASCII order.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c.aspx

In your example, "h" (U+0048) is before "dash" (U+2013), so "hello" will appear before "-less".  "." (U+002E) is before both, so ".net" appears first.

Comment: Wrong explanation. Try to sort "aa", "-bb" and "cc" and you'll see that the unicode order doesn't matter here. More likely that the comparer "eats" leading points and dashes.