# Find the minimum of a number sequence with negative numbers with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, numbers, range, minimum

The following code doesn't give the expected minimum -1. Instead I get 0.
Do you know why?

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string numbers = "-1 0 1 2 3 4 5";
        Console.WriteLine (numbers.Split (' ')[0]);     // output: -1
        string max = numbers.Split(' ').Max();
        string min = numbers.Split(' ').Min();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", max, min);         // output: "5 0"
    }
}
```

Comment: But why does it give me the output "5 0"? This shouldn't work then.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But `numbers` is an array of strings, so `.Max()` is comparing strings using `IComparable<String>.CompareTo()`

Comment: like @MatthewWatson said - Imagine sorting chars from A-Z. Z will be the last in sort order and Z will be the result of .Max() on this collection

Comment: @kame - You are right I've added an answer explaining why that is so

Comment: `"0"` is alphabetically less that `"-"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not fully defined an answer yet but it appears to be because the `-` isn't accounted for.. you can confirm this with `CompareOrdinal`

```
    Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal("-1", "0"));  // -3 meaning -1 min
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("-1", "0"));  // 1 meaning 0 min
```

Either way, you are trying to compare numbers so you should treat them as numbers so similar subtleties dont appear.

---

Attempted explanation...

String implements `IComparable<string>` so [String.Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) uses that implementation (see remarks). Which in turn uses [`CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

Now in the notes for this method

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The CompareTo(String) method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. For example, if the following code is run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a comparison of **"animal"** with **"ani-mal"** (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent.

(Emphasis mine)

As you see. the `-` is ignored hence 0 which has a smaller value in an ascii table is used for the comparison

Comment: However, the OP is NOT using character U00AD. He's using a minus sign/normal hyphen. U002D - and `"animal".CompareTo("ani-mal")` returns `-1` not `0`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Thanks, I didn't actually check that as the docs lead me to believe it would be equal in their example. I was just trying to find a definitive link between the OP's character and the ignorable character set

Comment: It's still more-or-less the right answer, because it IS happening because "-" is being treated specially by `String.CompareTo()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a string so Getting max from string is totally different than getting max from a number. For instance if You would have an array like below

> char[] someCharArray = new char[] { '1', '12', '2' }

calling Max() on this array would result with 2 as 2 is "higher" in string order than 12.

Thinking about Max/Min value from string/char You need to think about alphabetical order. If You have a colection of letters A-Z, calling Min() will return A, calling Max() will return Z.

To get Max/Min in numerical order You need to cast to some Number type like int.
See below:

```
string numbers = "-1 0 1 2 3 4 5";
int min = numbers.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Min();
Console.WriteLine(min); // gives You -1
```

Comment: His question is also why you can use `Min/Max` if those are strings and not numbers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right. I added explanation. Thanks.

Comment: In an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) the `-` is lower than the `0` so that doesn't explain this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for this behaviour:

1. You are sorting strings instead of numbers. This means that behind the scenes, Linq is using `String.CompareTo()` to compare the strings.
2. `String.CompareTo()` has special behaviour for `-`, which it treats as a HYPHEN and not a MINUS. (Note: This hyphen should not be confused with a soft hyphen which has the character code U00AD.)

Consider this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("-1".CompareTo("0")); // 1
Console.WriteLine("-1".CompareTo("1")); // 1
Console.WriteLine("-1".CompareTo("2")); // -1
```

Notice how, counter-intuitively, the "-1" is AFTER "0" and "1" but BEFORE "2".

This explains why when ordering the strings, the "-1" is neither the max nor the min.

[Also see the answer to this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680523/why-does-less-sort-after-hello-instead-of-before-it)