# Linq OrderBy not sorting correctly 100% of the time

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using the Linq `OrderBy()` function to sort a generic list of Sitecore items by display name, then build a string of pipe-delimited guids, which is then inserted into a Sitecore field. The display name is a model number of a product, generally around 10 digits. At first it seemed like this worked 100% of the time, but the client found a problem with it...

[image]

This is one example that we have found so far. The code somehow thinks `IC-30R-LH` comes after `IC-30RID-LH`, but the opposite should be true.

I put this into an online alphabetizer like [this one](http://alphabetizer.flap.tv/) and it was able to get it right...

[image]

I did try adding `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as a second parameter to the `OrderBy()` but it did not help.

Here's the code... Let me know if you have any ideas. Note that I am not running this `OrderBy()` call inside of a loop, at any scope.

```
    private string GetAlphabetizedGuidString(Item i, Field f)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        StringBuilder scGuidBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if (i != null && f != null)
        {
            foreach (ID guid in ((MultilistField)f).TargetIDs)
            {
                Item target = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").Items.GetItem(guid);
                if (target != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.DisplayName)) items.Add(target);
            }

            // Sort it by item name.
            items = items.OrderBy(o => o.DisplayName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();

            // Build a string of pipe-delimited guids.
            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                scGuidBuilder.Append(item.ID);
                scGuidBuilder.Append("|");
            }

            // Return string which is a list of guids.
            return scGuidBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd('|');
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the character code of the dash that seems to be making it out of order? It might not be the 45 of an ordinary "-".

Comment: Is the sorting behavior consistent?

Comment: I believe Craig W. answer is what you need but some Googling quickly brought me to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680523/why-does-less-sort-after-hello-instead-of-before-it

Comment: Thanks @Starceaker I'll take a look at that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the following code:

```
var strings = new string[] { "IC-30RID-LH", "IC-30RID-RH", "IC-30R-LH", "IC-30R-RH"};
var sorted = strings.OrderBy(s => s);
```

I was also able to get the desired sort order by adding a comparer to the sort.

```
var sorted = strings.OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

That forces a character-by-character (technically byte-by-byte) comparison of the two strings, which puts the '-' (45) before the 'I' (73).